# Center and set auto width CSS

Tags: html, css, center, nav, navbar

I've been trying to do this for a while but I can't seem to get my navbar centered and I want to have it adjust it's width to everything that is inside it.

```
<nav>
    <ul id="menu" class="black">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e4fa6/

Comment: One option is to change the display value of `#menu` to inline-block and use `text-align: center;` on the containing `<nav>` - http://jsfiddle.net/e4fa6/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `display: table;` to center auto width elements.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/e4fa6/4/

```
nav {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple of changes I've made, setting your li to:

```
#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Also having your #menu as:

```
#menu {
  text-align: center;
```

}

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/e4fa6/2/

Answer (score 0):

I forked your fiddle with the updates: http://jsfiddle.net/dvdNf/

I added `width: 25%;` and `text-align: center;` to your `<li>`s